# Semantic UI Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, semantic-ui

I have just switched from Bootstrap to Semantic-UI and I started to design a page, but nothing javascript related works (dropdowns, popups, etc). Here is the header code that I am using

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700|Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/semantic.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/semantic.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem - javascript not working. Did you figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: is Scala with Semantic- ui good combination? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about the play framework, so this is just a guess. Probably you have to initialize the component (dropdown etc.). At least you have to do this when using the Meteor.js framework.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```